# Bibliography in LaTeX: Spaces between words

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm writing the bibliography. LaTeX don't write it well. I don't know why. I have tried the tow methods: `\begin{thebibliography}` and using BiBTeX. The result is the same.

The result is longer spaces between some words.

[image]

Anybody can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
(La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Comment: Looks like your text is just getting justified.